# Computing a limit of a very complicated complex exponential expression; Fourier Transform of $\tan(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function, fourier-transform, continuity

**1. BACKGROUND**

I stumbled upon this problem while doing something very unusual -- computing the Fourier Transform of the tangent function.

I got that:

$$\mathcal{F}\{\tan(x)\}=-i\cdot\Bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi ixf}\,dx\;-\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{2e^{-2\pi ixf}\over e^{2ix}+1}\,dx\Bigg)$$

The first integral computes to $\delta(f)$, the dirac delta function. The other integral is very messy. I won't show my computations here because they are way too long to write out (I hope they are correct), but I got an infinite series, which is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{2e^{-2\pi ixf}\over e^{2ix}+1}\,dx\;=\;{1\over i}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Bigg((-1)^{k+1}\,\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\pi f-k)}{\Gamma(\pi f+1)}\,\cdot\Bigg[\frac{e^{2ix(k-\pi f)}}{(e^{2ix}+1)^{k+1}}\Bigg]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}\Bigg)$$

**2. THE PROBLEM**

The infinite series contains a problematic expression, that I have no idea how to compute. More precisely, it is:

$$\Bigg[\frac{e^{2ix(k-\pi f)}}{(e^{2ix}+1)^{k+1}}\Bigg]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}$$

Which means the same thing as:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigg[\frac{e^{2ix(k-\pi f)}}{(e^{2ix}+1)^{k+1}}\Bigg]\;-\;\lim_{x\to-\infty}\Bigg[\frac{e^{2ix(k-\pi f)}}{(e^{2ix}+1)^{k+1}}\Bigg]$$

At this point, I tried everything from L'Hopital's rule to decomposition of complex exponentials into trigonometric functions (and using trigonometric properties). I have considered changing the exponentials into geometric series, but haven't been able to do so...I don't even know how to do this at that point, and I'm not sure that would help anyhow.

I expect a discrete answer: something in terms of (or similar to) the dirac delta function, which would make the most sense with such a weird expression like this. But to be honest, I have no idea whether this expression even exists or converges...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have been told by people elsewhere, that tan(x) doesn't respect drichlet conditions, so the FT doesn't exist, and there's no point of computing that limit anyways. That's what happens if you experiment too much with a topic that you don't know much about..

Comment: Well, what do you know. I thought that $\tan$ was not a tempered distribution, and so that it was not Fourier-transformable, but now I see that you can go around that problem. Interesting.

Comment: What may be relevant is that $\int_0^\infty \tan x dx=\ln 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we define $\tan$ to be the distribution understood in the sense of the principal value. Then we can compute its Fourier coefficients and use the [general formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067819) for the Fourier transform of a periodic function:
$$\frac 1 \pi \int_0^\pi e^{-2 i k t}\tan t \, dt =
(-1)^k i \operatorname{sgn} k, \\
(\tan t, e^{-2 \pi i f t}) =
i \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} (-1)^k \hspace {1px}
 \delta {\left( f - \frac k \pi \right)} \operatorname{sgn} k.$$

Comment: This is the best answer, rigorous and clear. I have just one concern, as I already said in comments to the main question. Is $\tan$ a tempered distribution? That does not look obvious to me. There are probably some technicalities here, concerning the definition of "periodic distributions".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $-\ln \left| \cos t \right|$ is a locally integrable function; $\sum_k \int_{\pi k}^{\pi (k + 1)} \phi'(t) \ln \left| \cos t \right| \, dt$ exists, and one can show that it's equal to $\sum_k \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{\pi k}^{\pi (k + 1)} \phi(t) \tan t \, dt$. Therefore we can take this as the definition for $(\tan, \phi)$.

Comment: I have given you the best answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From a table in Bracewell:

$$\mathscr{F}\left\{\mathrm{III}(x)H(x)\right\} = \dfrac{1}{2}-i\dfrac{1}{2}\cot(\pi s)$$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside unit step function, and $\mathrm{III}(x)$ is an infinite $\delta(x)$ impulse train.

So one can use Fourier Transform properties, $\delta(x)$ function properties, and trigonometric identities, to find the Fourier Transform of $\tan(x)$.

$$\begin{align*}\ \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}-i\dfrac{1}{2}\cot(\pi x)\right\} &= \mathrm{III}(s)H(-s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{1\right\}-i\mathscr{F}\left\{\cot(\pi x)\right\} &= 2\mathrm{III}(s)H(-s)\\
\\
-i\mathscr{F}\left\{\cot(\pi x)\right\} &= 2\mathrm{III}(s)H(-s) - \delta(s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\cot(\pi x)\right\} &= 2i\mathrm{III}(s)H(-s) - i\delta(s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\cot(x)\right\} &= 2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-\pi s) - i\pi\delta(\pi s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\cot(x)\right\} &= 2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s) - i\delta(s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right\} &= 2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s) - i\delta(s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{-\tan\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\} &= 2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s) - i\delta(s)\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\} &= i\delta(s)-2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s) \\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\} &= e^{-i2\pi\frac{-\pi}{2} s}\left[i\delta(s)-2\pi i\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s)\right] \\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(x\right)\right\} &= ie^{i\pi^2 s}\left[\delta(s)-2\pi \mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-s)\right] \\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(x\right)\right\} &= 2\pi ie^{i\pi(\pi s)}\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(\pi s)-\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-\pi s)\right] \\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan\left(x\right)\right\} &= 2\pi i(-1)^{\pi s}\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(\pi s)-\mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-\pi s)\right] \\
\\
\end{align*}$$

**Update to compute the Fourier Transform of $\tan(x)$ more directly**

By performing the long division of the exponential form of $\tan(\pi x)$, the Fourier Transform can be computed without relying on an uncommon table entry:

$$\begin{align*} \mathscr{F}\left\{\tan(\pi x)\right\} &= \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\cos(\pi x)}\right\} = -i\mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{e^{i\pi x}-e^{-i\pi x}}{e^{i\pi x}+e^{-i\pi x}}\right\}\\
\\
&= -i\mathscr{F}\left\{1 - 2e^{-2\pi i x}+2e^{-4\pi i x}-2e^{-6\pi ix} + \dots \right\}\\
\\
&= -i\mathscr{F}\left\{-1 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-2\pi i k x}\right\}\\
\\
&= i\mathscr{F}\left\{1 - 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-2\pi i k x}\right\}\\
\\
&= i\left[\delta(s) - 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \delta(s+k)\right]\\
\\
&= 2i\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(s) - (-1)^s \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \delta(s+k)\right]\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan(\pi x)\right\} &= 2i(-1)^s \left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(s) - \mathrm{III}(s)H(-s)\right]\\
\\
\mathscr{F}\left\{\tan(x)\right\} &= 2\pi i(-1)^{\pi s} \left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(\pi s) - \mathrm{III}(\pi s)H(-\pi s)\right]\\
\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wow, so it's actually possible! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just one more question, do you think that my approach would get me to the answer if I somehow managed to compute the limit?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work.  If I had to do the integral, I would attempt to use contour integration to get the result.

Comment: Ok, thank you for help.

Comment: I am a bit concerned about that $(-1)^{\pi s}$. What does that mean?

Comment: Bracewell, *The Fourier Transform and Its Applications*, third edition, page 587 gives $\operatorname{III}(x) \operatorname{sgn} x \to -i \cot \pi s$. The issue is that if you define $\tan$ in the natural way as the principal value, the distributional sum $\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k e^{-2 \pi i k x}$ does not give $\tan$, it gives $\tan$ plus an impulse train.

Comment: I wonder, why there are no similar details on Laplace transform as on Fourier transform.