# What's the proof that $\int_0^\infty \tan x\,dx=\ln 2$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, regularization

What's the proof that $\int_0^\infty \tan x\,dx=\ln 2$?

https://mathoverflow.net/a/349627/10059

Comment: One can only prove propositions that have a meaning. Can you please provide your definition of $\int$ ?

Comment: Does it converge?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3259937/8157), it should be relevant. Also the other answer

Comment: So, do not simply write "$\int_0^\infty \tan x\,dx=\ln 2$" (which is false in the usual sense).  Instead you should write "$\int_0^\infty \tan x\,dx=\ln 2$ in the distributional sense."  Or some other wording that has a chance of being true.

Comment: @GEdgar In Cesaro and Cauchy principal value sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $0$-at-$0$ antiderivative $\ln|\sec x|$ is periodic with mean $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\ln\sec xdx$, which is [famously](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h125460p711573) $\ln 2$. If we [regard the antiderivative as equal to its own mean at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Ces%C3%A0ro_summability_of_an_integral), $\int_0^\infty\tan xdx=\ln 2$.

Comment: Isn't it more an act of faith than a proof?

Comment: @Gribouillis it's more a clarification of how we're defining $\int_0^\infty f^\prime(x)dx$, namely as $\Bbb E f(x)-f(0)$ instead of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-f(0)$. Obviously, the latter is undefined.

Comment: @Gribouillis it is Cesaro integration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Ces%C3%A0ro_summability_of_an_integral